# Sending mails from WCF application via smtp-relay

Tags: c#, .net, email, smtp, smtpclient

I'm not sure if this is the correct place to ask this question. But in my solution we have encountered a problem with sending mails.

Tech details:
I telnet the smtp-relay and get a response.

We send some emails from the application and it works.

And after a while the messages does not get sent and I can't telnet the smtp-server.

Then we need to restart the server and it works for a while.

The code that sends the message is:

```
    protected virtual void Send(Email mailMessage)
    {
        using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(this._mailService.SmtpContext.SmtpServer, this._mailService.SmtpContext.SmtpPort))
        {
            client.EnableSsl = _mailService.SmtpContext.EnableSsl;

            if (_mailService.SmtpContext.UseDefaultCredentials)
            {
                client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            }
            else
            {
                NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential(this._mailService.SmtpContext.Username, this._mailService.SmtpContext.Password);
                client.Credentials = credentials;
            }

            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;

            try
            {
                client.Send(mailMessage);
            }
            catch (SmtpException e)
            {
                /// LOG
            }

            /// Trigger mail sent event
            onMailSent(this, mailMessage);
        }
    }
```

I would like to know if anyone has faced an issue like this, and if there exist a solution.

We can see a connection being created in netstat, but it doesn't get removed. Is it some kind of error in the smptclient disposal?

Comment: My first thought on this is that its a permission issue.  The next question is how many emails are being fired at the server and at what frequency?

Comment: You mean that the permission is granted for a while, and then its not. Think we sent like 100-200 mails yesterday, and unable to send today.

Comment: technically yes and no.  The machine(s) that the emails are being sent from, is there any firewall rule or ports that need opening up on the exchange server to allow these machines to directly interact with it?

Comment: @Simon Price: The thing is that after a machine restart, we are able to send some mails and then at a point it just stops working. There are rules in the firewall added for port 25 and the smtp-relay we are using.

Comment: ok, in the catch, whats the exception and inner exception message that you get?

Comment: have you had any more failures today?

Comment: I ended up setting up a new server dedicated for sending mails and created a service that derived from the smtp-client wrappers i've created. It turned out that at the same point, the server didn't allow ANY outgoing traffic, so FTPs were unaccesible and so on as well. I'm not really sure why, but maybe some other objects in the aplpication that arent disposed of which fills the stacks on the server?